# NServiceBus Outbox with RavenDB persistence clean up / DeduplicationDataCleanup design

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus, nservicebus5

I'm looking into an issue where we're seeing CPU usage maxed out on a RavenDB instance using NServiceBus outbox implementation.

The design currently has all outbox workers configuring the deduplicationdatacleanup settings in their start up configuration. i.e. these settings:

endpointConfiguration.SetTimeToKeepDeduplicationData(TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
endpointConfiguration.SetFrequencyToRunDeduplicationDataCleanup(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

If you've got multiple workers that are processing messages for the system, should the cleanup be implemented on each of those, or should it be treated like a cronjob where you run the clean up process on just one of those workers, or a dedicated system in the environment that is not a worker, but more of a utility role?

I would imagine the latter, otherwise if you scale out workers, all of them are going to be trying to run the cleanup process every minute, or am I understanding the way this configuration executes the clean up incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of NServiceBus/Raven are you using?

Comment: Sorry for not updating you Hadi. NServiceBus 5.0 and RavenDB Server 3.5 are the versions.